# Is there a way to ask for access to local storage on a computer in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web-applications

I am trying to convert a Google Chrome App into a Web app. I have all the web app made except I ran into one problem. In the code it says,

`chrome.system.storage.getInfo(function(info){

```
  console.log(info);
  if(info[0].name == "MICROBIT" && info[0].type == "removable"){
    document.getElementById("bit?").innerHTML= "  YES!";
    document.getElementById("bit?").style.color = "green";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("bit?").innerHTML= "  NOPE!";
    document.getElementById("bit?").style.color = "red";
  }
});`
```

except when you are in the browser this doesn't work because you don't have access to the "chrome.system.storage". Is there a way to get access to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That API is only available to extensions. If you want storage, use localStorage or sessionStorage instead.

Comment: ... , indexDB or web sql